# Make the oracle backup files in other space via ftp

Tags: database, oracle, ftp, backup

I'm using Oracle 11g XE and I want to make the backup files in an other space that I can connect to it just via ftp.

Is it possible to run a script like :

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST = 'ftp: // user:password @ ftpserver_url';
```

or *Is there any other way to do it ?*

If not, How can I transfer the backup files to the other space automatically via ftp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not using ftp.

You could backup on a hard mounted nfs volume.

Comment: So how can I transfer the backup files to the other space automatically via ftp ?

Comment: not automagically. You could run a regular backup and transfer the resulting files using a ftp script.